# I wanna store multiple map values in single key of Redis in my Java Code

Tags: java, dictionary, redis

Here Below, I'm having one list of HashMap's and I wanna store all of these map's in single key of redis but I'm not getting any method to store all these maps in single key. Please help me in this problem.

```
Jedis jedis = new Jedis("localhost");
List <HashMap<String, String>> listOfMaps = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
listOfMaps.add(new HashMap<String,String>);
listOfMaps.add(new HashMap<String,String>);
listOfMaps.add(new HashMap<String,String>);
listOfMaps.add(new HashMap<String,String>);
.
.
.
and so on lets take upto 10 values
```

Now, I wanna store these maps in a key like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<listOfMaps.size();i++){
   jedis.hmset("mykey",listofMaps[i]);
}
```

But in his case hmset overwrites all older values to write new values.
Please tell me any alternative to store all these map values in single key **mykey**.

Comment: first use hmget - now add your new entry from listOfMaps to it - then put it back using hmset

Comment: I already tried it but when i'm using hmset it again replaces the previous value of map. My main motive is to store all these map values in a key.

Comment: hmset represents a single hash table in redis. How do you want to represent multiple hash table in a single hashmap in redis ? Since all your hash tables look like <string, string> why not add them as different attribute values to same key. ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Multimap` object provided by [Redisson](https://redisson.org) framework. It allows to store multiple values per map key as list or set. Here is the example:

```
RMultimap<String, Integer> multimap = redisson.getListMultimap("myMultimap");
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    myMultimap.put("someKey", i);
}
// returns Redis list object
RList list = myMultimap.get("someKey");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like below

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    List<String> valSetOne = new ArrayList<String>();
    valSetOne.add("ABC");
    valSetOne.add("BCD");
    valSetOne.add("DEF");

    List<String> valSetTwo = new ArrayList<String>();
    valSetTwo.add("CBA");
    valSetTwo.add("DCB");

    map.put("FirstKey", valSetOne);
    map.put("SecondKey", valSetTwo);

    for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {

        String key = entry.getKey();

        List<String> values = entry.getValue();

        System.out.println("Value of " + key + " is " + values);

    }

}
```